# HttpWebRequest: post method using "useUnsafeHeaderParsing = true"

Tags: vb.net, post, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a third party website, and then get the source code.

 It worked well for me, and after some time I tried sign in again and then i got an error message:

 "**{" The server committed a protocol violation. Section = ResponseStatusLine "}**.

 After quick search on google i found out that i sholud to add to  "app.config" the following entry: `<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = true/>`

After that it worked fine. But, I get the source code as a guset, and not as "connected User".

I tried another site that does not require "UseUnsafeHeaderParsing = true" 
 and it worked well.
It looks like "UseUnsafeHeaderParsing = true" disruptive cookies?

*Sorry for my english, this is not my native language.

this is my code:

```
Private siteCookies As New Net.CookieContainer()

    Function siteRequest(url As String, ByVal Method As String, Optional ByVal data As String = Nothing) As String
        Static soucrecode As String = Nothing
        Const UserAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
        Try

            Dim Request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
            Request.Accept = "*/*"
            Request.Timeout = 10000
            Request.Method = Method
            Request.UserAgent = UserAgent
            Request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            Request.CookieContainer = siteCookies
            If Request.Method = "POST" AndAlso data IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim postBytes() As Byte = New UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(data)
                Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
                Request.GetRequestStream().Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
            End If

            Dim Response As Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
            soucrecode = New IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd()
            Response.Close()
        Catch e As Exception
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message)

        End Try
        Return soucrecode
    End Function
```

using:

```
txtLoginSoucre.Text = siteRequest("http://www.SomeSite.com/login.php?do=login", "Post", "username=myUser&password=MyPass") ' Login to site
txtSoucre.Text siteRequest("http:  //www.SomeSite.com", "Get") 'Grab soucrecode
```

Comment: anyone that can help?

Comment: It looks like the server response is invalid, i.e not a valid HTTP response. Enable logging  (http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html ) and see the logfile. Maybe put the actual response in the post so that we can take a look and advise.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`Request.KeepAlive = False`